# Using AddCheckTool Method in wx.ToolBar class in wxPython library

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to use toolbar using wxPython library and this is a part of code :

```
toolbar2 = wx.ToolBar(self, wx.TB_HORIZONTAL | wx.TB_TEXT)
self.position = wx.TextCtrl(toolbar2)
bold = wx.Bitmap('icons\\1\\stock_text_bold.png',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
toolbar2.AddCheckTool(-1, bold)
```

at the last line I get this error :

```
TypeError: ToolBar.AddCheckTool(): argument 2 has unexpected type 'Bitmap'
```

So what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `label`

```
AddCheckTool(self, toolId, label, bitmap1, bmpDisabled=NullBitmap, shortHelp="", longHelp="", clientData=None)
```

for Phoenix:

```
toolbar2.AddCheckTool(-1, "Bold", bold)
```

for Classic:

```
toolbar.AddCheckLabelTool(-1, "Bold", bold)
```

Should sort that out.